# jsFiddler shows one thing with code vs Visual Studio

Tags: css, html

I'm really stumped here. This fiddler [Test Style](http://jsfiddle.net/tDD36/1/) (shown below also since stack overflow wouldn't let me just link to fiddler without posting code myself) works the way I'm looking for in fiddler. However with this exact same code in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express the main menu part is correct, but the player select part (the drop down and 3 buttons) does not have a gray background or some of the subtle centering format. What could possibly be the difference?

This happens even if I launch different browsers from VS. Could anyone maybe plug that jsFiddler code into a webpage in VS Web Developer 2010 Express and see if they see that the BG isn't gray in the player selection part?

HTML:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/LocalStorageDB.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Main.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My Golf Score</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divMainMenu">
        <input id="btnNewRound" type="button" value="New Round" onclick="return btnNewRound_onclick()" />
        <input id="btnCurrentRound" type="button" value="Current Round" onclick="return btnCurrentRound_onclick()" />
        <input id="btnRoundHistory" type="button" value="Round History" onclick="return btnRoundHistory_onclick()" />
        <input id="btnReports" type="button" value="Reports" onclick="return btnReports_onclick()" />
    </div>
    <div id="divPlayerSelect">
        <div id="divPlayerSelectName">
            Player:
            <select id="lstPlayer">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="divPlayerSelectButtons">
            <input id="btnNewPlayer" type="button" value="New Player" onclick="return btnNewPlayer_onclick()" />
            <input id="btnBackPlayer" type="button" value="Back" onclick="return btnBackPlayer_onclick()" />
            <input id="btnDonePlayer" type="button" value="Done" onclick="return btnDonePlayer_onclick()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body 
        {
            text-align: center;
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        td,th 
        {
         text-align: center;
        }
        #divMainMenu
        {
            margin: auto;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            background-color: Gray;
            border: 1px solid red
        }
        #divMainMenu input[type="button"]
        {
            display: block;
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 14%;
            margin-bottom: 2.5%;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 2.5%;
            font-size: 400%;
        }
        /* START: Player select window*/
        #divPlayerSelect
        {
            border: 10px solid blue;
            background-color: Gray;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 150%;
        }
        #divPlayerSelectName
        {
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 200%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
        }
        #divPlayerSelectName select
        {
            width: 50%;
            height: 200%;
            font-size: 85%;
        }
        #divPlayerSelectButtons
        {
            border: 1px solid green;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #divPlayerSelectButtons input
        {
            width: 25%;
            height: 15%;
            font-size: 200%;
            margin: 5px;
        }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out from that fiddle that you probably dont have in your project: first, the DOCTYPE. The DOCTYPE you have listed on your page differs from the one actually loaded on the fiddle, which is the HTML5 DOCTYPE, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so switch your current DOCTYPE to that one. Its much nicer anyways. Second is the use of the `normalize.css` sheet, which resets the elements on the page, so make sure you have that also included on your project.

**Edit**

Another issue, your scripts are not being loaded within the `<head>` tag.

Comment: The DOCTYPE looks the exact same from the fiddle to what I posted above to me. Not sure why you see a difference. I've never heard of normalize.css. What would the href be for that? I did a google for this and seems google has one. Is that the defacto one to use?

Comment: @user441521 the DOCTYPE being rendered in the fiddle is different from what you have, take a look at the source of the full screen version: http://jsfiddle.net/tDD36/1/show/

Comment: I see. Didn't seem to help any though (also put the script tags in the header). Do you have VS? If so are you able to see it?

Comment: @user441521 Im not on my work machine right now. Make sure you are also including the [normalize.css](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css) sheet as well.

Comment: I am. Updated the original post with the new HTML. I think I have it all right.

Comment: @user441521 no matter how i look at it everything looks the same to me. Ill test it out on VS when i get a chance.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it's not making any sense. Everything looks right but just getting different results.

Comment: I just ran into a crazy issue. If I started to recreate the html tags and then the css it started working (even though I was typing word for word what it was before). Then after setting one value it went back to being screwed up. I undo what I just typed, and didn't matter it was messed up now. I mean what is that.

Comment: Also found out if I do these styles in the html tags it works. VS is screwing something up when done outside of the html tags. I originally had it in the HTML file but not inside the tags and got the same result. But it's also strange building from VS produced the same code in all major browsers.